# Using Python Threads, how can I wait until ALL queues are finished before the threads join?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have 2 different Queues, A and B, being handled by their own threads. Thread A pulls pages off the internet, thread B scans all the links from that page and adds them to thread A's queue. As you can imagine, a single queue can go empty temporarily, until it's companion thread adds more for it to do. But since either can go temporarily empty at any time, I don't want them to unblock as soon as one goes empty, only when BOTH go empty in the same instance.

How can I accomplish this? My pseudocode, the real deal is too messy

```
QueueA
QueueB

ThreadA:
    pull page
    put raw HTML in QueueB

ThreadB:
    pull links from raw HTML
    add links to QueueA


QueueA.join()
QueueB.join()
```

I've also tried this, using a QueueC to check if both the other queues are empty, that it will unblock so that QueueA and B can unblock too:

```
QueueA
QueueB
QueueC

ThreadA:
    pull page
    put raw HTML in QueueB

ThreadB:
    pull links from raw HTML
    add links to QueueA

ThreadC:
    queues = QueueC.get()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1) 
        for q in queues:
            if q.full():
                return
        self.parent_queue.task_done()           

QueueC.join()
QueueA.join()
QueueB.join()
```

As you can see, if QueueA ever goes empty, all it's threads die and won't be revived. What's the appropriate way of solving this?

(And I've spent countless hours researching it, unless I've missed something I cannot find a reference to this specific type of problem, thanks for your help!)

Comment: Don't stop the two worker threads at all. If you make them background (daemon) threads, they won't interfere with the rest of your program. Since they are blocked waiting for input on their queues, they won't take CPU time either. Otherwise, you could try to keep track of any unhandled URLs and if there are none left, you could terminate the threads. This requires some kind of bookkeeping though, shared between threads which must be properly synced.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So my concern is, as soon as these 2 threads are done, I want it to halt. What I've tried implementing is a 3rd queue that looks to see if q.full(), and if both are not, then the 3rd queue will join, and the other 2 can then join. It doesn't seem to be working though, any thoughts? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: You want the two threads to terminate when there is nothing left to do. There is nothing left when all started tasks are finished. So, when adding the initial URL to the queue, the number of tasks is incremented to one. After downloading that URL, you create a task in queue B and only then decrement the number of finished tasks, so it goes from one to two and back to one. Only if that reaches zero, you terminate. In order to coordinate the two threads, use a `threading.Condition` object.